# How to split a hexadecimal string into an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, split, hex

I have this string

```
string in = "Two One Nine Two";
```

I convert it to hexadecimal using the following function

```
    std::string string_to_hex(const std::string& input)
{
    static const char* const lut = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    size_t len = input.length();

    std::string output;
    output.reserve(2 * len);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned char c = input[i];
        output.push_back(lut[c >> 4]);
        output.push_back(lut[c & 15]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

now, how to split it into an array like this

```
int plain[16] = {0x54,0x77,0x6F,0x20,0x4F,0x6E,0x65,0x20,0x4E,0x69,0x6E,0x65,0x20,0x54,0x77,0x6F};
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the assignment.  For example, the character `w` is not a hexadecimal value.  Maybe you need to convert "Two" to the digit 2 before converting to hex.

Comment: If you iterate over the result from `input.c_str()`, you will notice that it is an array like your `plain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
string in = "Two One Nine Two";
strncpy(&plain[0], in.c_str(), 16);
```

The string literal is already stored in memory in the format that you want.
I'm showing one method to copy it to an array of character.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do...

What you need to do is [tokenize the input string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53921/342) with the space being the delimiter.

Once you have that it is a simple matter of matching the words to numbers - a simple `compare` or use if `==` will do.